# Vue, compare two arrays and check if results match

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I need to create a theater app. I have a JSON file with two arrays. Sections and groups. I'm able to load both arrays in my Vue app but I need to compare them and find matches. Array 1 contains seats and array 2 contains the reservations. I use a simple `v-for` attribute to loop trough the first array (sections) and I'm able to show the results/seats. How can I compare array 1 with array 2 and for example add a class to the seat when the objects are the same and if a seat is occupied?

- A section has a name, rows and seats.
- A group has a name, rows and a seat.

In my opinion I have to check if seat in a row from a name match with the section. If so I can add the id as a class.

The JavaScript part to load the JSON data

```
export default {
    name: 'app',
    data() {
        return {
            json: [],
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            "url": url
        }).then(result => {
            this.json = result.data;
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    },

}
```

The HTML loop to show the sections, but not the occupied seat

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in json.sections" v-bind:key="index">
  <h3>{{ item.name }}</h3>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in item.rows" v-bind:key="index">
      <div class="rownr">{{ item.row }} </div>
        <div v-for="(item, index) in item.seats" v bind:key="index"v-bind:class=item.rank>
          <div :class=item.row>
            <div v-for="(group, index) in json.groups" v-bind:key="index">
              <div v-for="(group, index) in group.seats" v-bind:key="index">{{ item.seat}}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JSON file (part)

```
{
"sections": [{
        "name": "balcony",
        "rows": [{
                "row": "1",
                "seats": [{
                        "seat": "1",
                        "rank": "rank1"
                    },
                    {
                        "seat": "3",
                        "rank": "rank1"
                    },
                    {
                        "seat": "4",
                        "rank": "rank1"
                    },
                    {
                        "seat": "2",
                        "rank": "rank1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "row": "2",
                "seats": [{
                        "seat": "1",
                        "rank": "rank1"
                    ...
            },

        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "main hall",
        "rows": [{
                "row": "1",
                "seats": [{
                        "seat": "1",
                        "rank": "rank1"
                    },
                    {
                        "seat": "3",
                        "rank": "rank3"
                    },
                    ...
            {
                "row": "2",
                "seats": [{
                        "seat": "1",
                        "rank": "rank2"
                    },
                }
],
"groups": [{
        "id": "1",
        "seats": [{
                "section": "main hall",
                "row": "2",
                "seat": "4"
            },
            {
                "section": "main hall",
                "row": "1",
                "seat": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "seats": [{
                "section": "main hall",
                "row": "2",
                "seat": "6"
            },
            {
                "section": "main hall",
                "row": "2",
                "seat": "5"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Comment: From your sample data it seems that the `sections` part does not contain the seats that are in the `groups` part and vice versa. Is this representative? Does that mean that reserved seats only appear in `groups` and that those in `sections` all represent free seats?

Comment: sections are all available seats. groups are the reserved seats.

Comment: This is not the final data. But the issue is how to compare both arrays and let them communicate to find matches.

Comment: Just to be sure. You write sections are all *available* seats. Do you mean all seats, or all *free* seats? "Available" is ambiguous here.

Comment: free seats, possible seats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could mutate the `json` variable so that the `seats` part gets extended with `groupId` properties in case the same seat is found in the `groups` section:

```
json.groups.forEach( ({id, seats}) =>
    seats.forEach( ({section, row, seat}) =>
        json.sections.find(s => s.name == section)
            .rows.find(r => r.row == row)
            .seats.find(s => s.seat == seat)
            .groupId = id
    )
);
```

This code assumes that seat references in the `groups` part *always* exist in the `sections` part. If not, you'll get an exception.

Now you can test the presence of the `groupId` property in your rendering loop and act accordingly.

#### When invalid seats occur

In case your `groups` data references sections, rows or seats that don't exist in the `sections` part, then an exception will be thrown. If you want to get more details about what is missing, then use this more elaborate code. It will list the offending section/row/seat:

```
json.groups.forEach( ({id, seats}) =>
    seats.forEach( ({section, row, seat}) => {
        const foundSection = json.sections.find(s => s.name == section);
        if (!foundSection) throw "Section " + section + " is referenced in groups, but that section does not exist in sections";
        const foundRow = foundSection.rows.find(r => r.row == row);
        if (!foundRow) throw "Section " + section + ", row " + row + " is referenced in groups, but that section/row does not exist in sections";
        const foundSeat = foundRow.seats.find(s => s.seat == seat);
        if (!foundSeat) throw "Section " + section + ", row " + row + ", seat " + seat + " is referenced in groups, but that section/row/seat does not exist in sections";
        foundSeat.groupId = id;
    })
);
```

Based on that information fix your input data so that a match can be made for *every* seat.

#### Rendering

The rendering part could use the `v-if` and `v-else` attributes:

```
{{ item.seat }}
<span v-if="'groupId' in item">occupied</span>
<span v-else>free</span>
```

Comment: I'm able to add this to axios but it says: Cannot set property 'groupId' of undefined. Also i'm not sure how to  test the presence of the 'groupId' property

Comment: The first error means that your `groups` has references to seats that don't exist in `sections`. That is what I asked about. If that cannot be guaranteed, please explain what the rule is. You can use things like `<div  v-if="groupId in item">occupied</div>` `<div v-else>free</div>`.

Comment: Almost, first of all, your solution works excellent and it is very clear now how to handle the process. With console.log every match is showed in my debugger, but in the app the only results I see are "free" and not "occupied". I added groupId: [] too else it couldn't find the variable. All references match by the way.

Comment: Indeed, there were single quotes missing in the final code block of my answer; Please see edit. For this to work you should not add `groupId: []`. It is not intended to be an array, and the idea was for the property to *not* be present when the seat is free.